# iOS Push Notifications not working with Development certificate

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, profile, apn

Situation: we have PROD and DEV APN certificates installed on different backend URLs. PRODUCTION certificate works!: pushes are delivered.

DEV certificate does not work, apple servers return error code 7 (invalid token). I have already checked all the stuff but may be I'm still missing something.

- app id is correct (same used for prod)
- i use right backend (with DEV certificate installed)
- I start the app from XCode in DEBUG mode (corresponds to DEV environment)
- I use proper app development certificate, from the same account
- I use proper dev profile (pushes are supported in it)

Should actually work, right?

Comment: Have you tested after creating dev apn? try this on the .pem files:   **$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 
    -cert YourCertHere.pem -key YourKeyHere.pem** and replace file names then  
**Enter pass phrase for YourKeyHere.pem:** and after that you should see if they are ok

Comment: I encountered the same problem. After upgrading to iOS 9, my app suddenly can't receive notification when in development mode. That is, app is installed from XCode and notification is sent using dev cert. It seems the token is invalid, but I followed Apple's instructions. The token is grabbed every time the app is launched. What's really weird is, if I send notification through prod cert, the development app can receive it! It seems somehow the iOS system thinks my app is in production?

Comment: @Shawn Same problem here. I think Apple screwed up again: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19993

Comment: Turns out we had a wrongly generated mobileprovision file. Nevermind then.

Comment: I ma also running my app using dev cert and used auth api to receive receive notifications but when I send notification from server it gives bad device token error @ArnieSchwarzvogel

Answer (score 2):

In case of IOS 9, please send notifications from Apple Production Push notification certificate, it will work.

Make pem file from Production APS certificate, and use this file both in development as well as production mode.

Moreover, use gateway of production in both cases which is "gateway.push.apple.com:2195"

Don't use "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195" even if you are sending notifications in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

The device token returned by the phone for push notifications is different in production and development. Make sure that your server uses an actual development device token (I'm not talking about the certificate but about the device identifier) when making a request to APNS.

If your device already run the production build of your app, the production token may be in your database and your server may try to use it. Depends on how you handled your user accounts though.

Comment: I had the same problem. Please see the comment above. Let me know if you have any idea. Thanks.